# Trace route to specific page on a website

Tags: linux-networking, ping, networking

If I can access a site (ie: serverfault.com) through my proxy/firewall, it means that it will allow all it's subdirectories (serverfault.com/*/*)?

I can access the website site.com/ but it returns me error 403.6, if I try to access site.com/secured/LicenseActivator.asmx

Comment: ...just because you can access the main site doesn't mean you can access other stuff. 403 is Forbidden.

Comment: You had to ask this on superuser.com. This site is for professional sysadmins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to access any https enabled site over your proxy/firewall?

You may have problem with your proxy settings regarding 443 port.

BTW, traceroute has nothing to do with http.

Comment: Do you have proxy logs? There is the answer to your question.

Comment: Could it be a blockage from this target website?

Comment: @titus A traceroute can be performed with any IP packet except from ICMP errors. Though performing a traceroute with a packet in the middle of an HTTP connection is complicated.